# Scanner.throwfor, next, nextInt errors. Can't figure out why

Tags: java

I am just starting to program in Java and trying to make a fahrenheit to celsius converter with user input. Thought I had it but I am now stuck. I am getting the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException    
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be great!

```
import java.util.*;

class Practicet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float Fahrenheit = 32;
        float Celsius = 0;
        Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do You Want to Enter Fahrenheit or Celsius: ");
        int userInput = option.nextInt();
        switch (userInput) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
                Fahrenheit = option.nextInt();
                Fahrenheit = (float) ((Fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8000);
                System.out.println("Temperature in Celsius = " + Fahrenheit);
                System.out.println("Thank You! ");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter temperature in Celsius: ");
                Celsius = option.nextFloat();
                Celsius = (float) ((Celsius * 1.8000) + 32);
                System.out.println("Temperature in Fahrenheit = " + Celsius);
                System.out.println("Thank You! ");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Something went wrong! ");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What input are you giving to your program?

Comment: When i run it I either put in Fahrenheit or Celsius. Then the errors come.

Comment: maybe because you replied `C` or `F` to the first question and neither `C` or `F` is an `int`? You need to enter `0` for fahrenheit and `1` for Celsius.

Comment: What does `nextInt()` do? Why are you entering words?

Comment: Think about the input your program is trying to read, then think about what you are giving it....  Your program works fine for me.

Comment: Ok nevermind its solved. Thank you azurefrog. I am an idiot

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your switch statement. The only way you receive an `InputMismatchException` would be if you entered an unexpected value. Try changing `int userInput = option.nextInt();` to `String userInput = option.next();` and change your cases from 0 and 1 to `"Fahrenheit"` and `"Celsius"`